# How to make button's "pushed" effect?

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 buttons that represents 3 states. I'd like when I push some of them that button stays in visual "push" state and other 2 are in normal non-pushed state.

Here's the code I use:

```js
if (itemType === 'default') {
  document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.remove('non-pushed');
  document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.add('pushed');
}
```

```css
.pushed {
  border-style: inset;
}

.non-pushed {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="defaultMode" class="non-pushed" onclick="setMode('link', 'default');">Default</button>
<button id="orthoMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'ortho');">Ortho</button>
<button id="cornerMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'corner');">Corner</button>
```

But, it's not working.

Comment: here, refer to this W3S article https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

Comment: You might want to define the setMode function that you try to call

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You could use Radio buttons instead and do it all in CSS :)

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/23jk5cau/ (and stay away from w3schools)

Comment: http://thestizmedia.com/radio-buttons-as-toggle-buttons-with-css/

Comment: https://codepen.io/Volorf/pen/rxgMZp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one way of how you can do what you want

When you click on a button you remove the class **pushed** from all buttons and then you add that class to the clicked button.

```js
function setMode(e, itemType) {

  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("pushed");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('pushed');
  });

  document.getElementById(itemType).classList.add('pushed');

}
```

```css
.pushed {
  border-style: inset;
}

button {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="defaultMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'defaultMode');">Default</button>
<button id="orthoMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'orthoMode');">Ortho</button>
<button id="cornerMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'cornerMode');">Corner</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JS!

Here's a CSS-only way:

```css
input.toggle {
  position:absolute;
  left:-20em;
}

input.toggle + label {
  border:1px solid black;
  background:lightgrey;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px grey;
  user-select: none;
}

input.toggle:checked + label {
  background:grey;
  box-shadow:none;
}

input.toggle:focus + label {
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="toggle" name="mode" value="default" id="default" checked>
<label for="default">Default</label>

<input type="radio" class="toggle" name="mode" value="ortho" id="ortho">
<label for="ortho">Ortho</label>

<input type="radio" class="toggle" name="mode" value="corner" id="corner">
<label for="corner">Corner</label>
```

If you need to know what mode has been selected:

```
let mode = document.querySelector('input[name=mode]:checked').value
console.log('Selected mode: ', mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. CSS is enough. Use `:active` pseudoclass.

```css
button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: outset 3px #666;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: inset 3px #666;  
}
```

```html
<button>Hello!</button>
```

Comment: With :active, if you click anywhere else in the page, no button is active any more.  So the button will not stay in its pushed state.

Answer (score 0):

`itemType` is **undefined** one .you should define `var itemType = 'default'`

or

You could create the function in DOM

```js
function setMode(link,itemType){
if (itemType === 'default') {
  document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.remove('non-pushed');
  document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.add('pushed');
  console.log(document.getElementById("defaultMode").outerHTML)
}
}
```

```css
.pushed {
    border-style: inset;
}

.non-pushed {
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="defaultMode" class="non-pushed" onclick="setMode('link', 'default')">Default</button>
<button id="orthoMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'ortho');">Ortho</button>
<button id="cornerMode" onclick="setMode('link', 'corner');">Corner</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS-only solution with actual buttons:

```css
.pushed {
  border-style: inset;
  margin: 0 1px
}

#buttons > span {
  position: relative;
}

#buttons input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0
}
#buttons input[type=radio]:checked ~ button {
  border: inset
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <span><input id="default" type="radio" name="mode" checked><button>Default</button></span>
  <span><input id="ortho" type="radio" name="mode"><button>Ortho</button></span>
  <span><input id="corner" type="radio" name="mode"><button>Corner</button></span>
</div>
```